# jQuery prepend not working with firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, prepend

I've got a structure set up like this:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

At some point, I want to prepend more "child"s to the container.

```
$("#container").prepend('<div class="child"></div>');
```

This works fine with all browsers except with Firefox. Firefox **appends** the new child. As a result, since the same code is used on page load, the children are actually upside down.

I've tried using everything from .innerHTML, .before(), using .html(child + old_html), etc etc, but I can't for the life of me get Firefox to prepend the html properly.

Thanks in advance if anyone can help me fix this.

Edit: added missing "

Comment: Can you create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: works ok for me: http://jsfiddle.net/ufomammut66/R4zxV/

Comment: No repro on Firefox 14 / jQuery 1.8 ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gbHws/)).

Comment: Works fine for me here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/hJyFb/ after I fix the typo you have in your selector.

Comment: Does it work in other browsers?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. This sure is odd, and I did notice it works on the jQuery.append() page, but that didn't work with divs, so I thought that that may be the issue but it appears to be it isn't.

Yes, it works in other browsers. I can't give you the link to the actual site, but I'll try to fix a page that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: In case it was missed, I've editted the main post to give a link to an example page where the bug shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, it appears that the prepend() was not at fault, but Firefox actually reversed my keys in the json. To illustrate what happend, my json looked like this:

```
{"shouts":[
"12"{<some data concerning id=12 here>}, 
"11"{<some data concerning id=11 here>}, 
"10"{<some data concerning id=10 here>},
etc ]}
```

Chrome, and all other browsers, reversed this order in the loop, since they probably assumed the "12", "11" and "10" as keys in the array. When looping, this would produce 10, 11, and 12. Firefox however, didn't do this, which led to the reversal.

The solution was to remove the IDs from the json (this made the behaviour uniform, ie. all browsers displayed it in reverse order now), and then reverse the order again for the json, which would produce this:

```
{"shouts":[
{<some data concerning id=10 here>}, 
{<some data concerning id=11 here>}, 
{<some data concerning id=12 here>},
etc ]}
```

That solved the problem! (As one can see from the example.php now.) Thanks for your help everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Your selector's string is not closed :

Change this:

```
$("#container).prepend('<div class="child"></div>');
```

To:

```
$("#container").prepend('<div class="child"></div>');
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, but please note I've written simplified code here. This was not the actual code but merely a structure so others can easily understand it.

Comment: @Wotuu First, I notice the same problem on your page with firefox, so you're not insane! :-) Your add_shout() function seems correct, I was thinking that maybe an unclosed <div> would cause trouble as the browser is trying to close it still. But I noticed you are using jQuery 1.6.1, there is only 1.6.4 on fiddle, have you tried updating your library?

Comment: Hi @gil, thanks for testing it out, at least I'm not going insane indeed! I've updated the jQuery version to the latest (1.8.0) for the site, but it's not working still. At least we eliminated that as a possible issue. Perhaps the issue lies in the loaded content, we allow users to enter full html (it's a website for only a few trusted users). Although a quick scan of the database returns negative, but I'll replace all the &lt; and &gt; with their html-code counterparts later tonight and see if that may be causing it (but again, this is highly unlikely). Thanks again.

Comment: Appearantly the $.each loop is running in different directions. I've placed some console.log() so you can see what is going on. The first log is the complete received json, every log after that is from inside the loop. Note that Firefox has the loop backwards compared to Chrome (and other browsers). I'll continue my investigation when I get home. Thanks so far guys!

Comment: Firefox : I get first json.shouts starting from 45 to 64. And then logs from 64 to 45. Safari Windows : same. Chrome: json.shouts 45 to 64, but logs from 45 to 64. IE9 has a terrible console and doesn't display objects but react just like Chrome. Rare to see two webkits not reacting the same Oô! So anyway, the problem is definitely coming from $.each() and not .prepend();

Comment: Few hints : Could you try logging the value of i, to see if it's really reversed. Also, try to force the parsing of your json with json=$.parseJSON(json); Just to rule out the default parsing as well.